# Best approach to write/read binary data in Little or Big Endian with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, endianness

Ok, if i've got a binary file encoded either in little endian or big endian under .NET, what is the best way to read / write to it?

In the .NET framework i've only managed to found BinaryWritters / BinaryReaders which use little endian as default, so my approach was implement my own BinaryReader / BinaryWritter for reading / writting data in big endian, but I wonder if there is a better aproach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this one:

[Miscellaneous Utility Library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)

Comment: I take the offer as nobody seems to know any solution implemented in the .NET framework itself. Thanks