# .NET BinaryReader not obeying encoding

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, binary, endianness

When reading in a Binary file using System.IO.BinaryReader the byte order seems to be unaffected when using any of the multi-byte Read methods.

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);
```

and

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
```

are producing the same results for me.

This is causing me a lot of frustration because I have to reverse the byte order constantly while reading in data structures.

[Screenshot - Big Endian Unicode](http://i.imgur.com/kT9e0.png)

[Screenshot - Little Endian Unicode](http://i.imgur.com/PEAQp.png)

I've tested this on .NET 3 through 4.5

Comment: I assume the BinaryRead only works on textfiles, but from the chunks in your code the file seems to be binary. Then as far as I know you have to handcode it using the Convert class

Comment: Or take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80784/best-approach-to-write-read-binary-data-in-little-or-big-endian-with-c?rq=1

Comment: What is the result if you specify encoding for the reader as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`BinaryReader` only uses the `Encoding` when handling `string` data (pretty much, just `ReadString()`). `ReadBytes` etc do not involve `Encoding` - it just reads the binary data. Since you only call `ReadBytes`, this (`Encoding`) never gets a look-in.

If the data is out-of-order, then it sounds like the file wasn't created with `BinaryWriter`. If it wasn't created with `BinaryWriter` then `BinaryReader` probably isn't all that useful - you could just use `Stream`.

Comment: A BinaryReader-like class can still be useful if you know the format - but if you need to switch endianness, EndianBinaryReader is what you want, from MiscUtil :)